# Improving performance of page in wicket 1.3

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I am using wicket-1.3 in my application and a page is divided in 2 parts, 1st is having categorySelector wicket id which is shown dropdown and based on the dropdown value category wicket id will be changed by application. see below code

```
<div wicket:id="categorySelector" >Category selection controls</div>
<div wicket:id="category" >Category Data</div>
```

I have select 1 value from categorySelector dropdown value and category panel will show data in Propertylistview and data size is around 4k but its taking time around 4-5 minutes to page load.

I want to know why its taking too much time and is there any other alternative approach to implement the functionality for load huge data.

I have seen pagination concept also but i think it will not help me also.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination should help you because you will load only slices of the data, not everything at once.

In addition the browser will have less HTML elements to render!

Comment: let me implement this way functionality.